# Selecting only from a specific table on a page WWW::Mechanize and CSS Selectors?

Tags: perl, css-selectors, web-scraping, www-mechanize, www-mechanize-firefox

Good day,

I am scraping a number of pages that display the data I require in tables. On the page there are multiple tables with the following:

```
<table class="dTable" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" border="0">
```

The items I want scraped are in table cells:

```
<td class="dCell" align="right">
```

There are unfortunately many cells on the page with the same class. Furthermore, certain pages contain extra `dCells` for additional information. So specifying the particular cells in the script of the form:

```
my @thing = $mech->selector('td.dCell');

my $val = $thing[14]->text();
```

Will give different results on different pages, ie. I won't get what I want to scrape all the time.

So as a part solution, I think it would be best to select from the specific table.

```
my @table = $mech->selector('table.dTable');

my @required = $table[3]->selector('td.dCell');

#the info is in the third dTable on the page

#the third table does not contain changing data, ie. I can use required[1] and it will be the same all of the time.
```

I tried this and it does not work, error received:

MozRepl::RemoteObject::Object has no function selector at the following line:

```
my @required = $table[3]->selector('td.dCell');
```

So at this point I'm stuck. I appreciate all the assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `node` option of the `selector`:

```
my @required = $mech->selector( 'td.dCell', { node => ... } );
```

But why you don't using XPath?

```
my @required = $mech->xpath('//table[@class="dTable"][3]//td[@class="dCell"]');
```

Comment: Thanks ganga, at first it didn't write results but then I changed it to `[@class="dTable][2]` and it worked. Funny thing is that in the html it is the 3rd `dTable` to appear

Comment: @StephenH In computer science, you start counting at 0 not 1. So the 1st table has position 0, 2nd table has position 1, etc

Comment: You make it sound like I'm a complete dunce. I meant to say the 4th `dTable` to appear. So it is one off...